# Issue with Interface Properties and Default Implementations in C#

Tags: c#, interface, properties, invisible

I'm encountering a problem with interface properties in C#. The predefined property **DefinedProperty** is not visible in the context of the class that implements the interface. Here is a code example:

```
interface IBase
{
    int Integer { get; set; }
    string DefinedProperty => Integer.ToString();
}
```

```
class Class : IBase
{
    public int Integer { get; set; }

    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DefinedProperty); // Compile time error here
    }
}
```

I'm hoping someone can provide a clear explanation if there is one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default interface methods and default values for Auto Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700939/default-interface-methods-and-default-values-for-auto-properties)

Comment: These implementation are on the interface not the class. You may think of it at they have been implemented explicitly in your class Class. Means you need to call them via the interface. In external code you presumably would have a IBase reference anyways but for internal usage in the class you would need to cast this to IBase first and then call the default implementation via the interface. `((IBase)this).DefinedProperty;`

Comment: Side note: are you absolutely sure you observe a run-time exception on "// Exception here" line? That is quite unlikely as the code should not compile. If it is the case please [edit] the post with more appropriate terminology (likely "compile time error here")

Comment: Thanks for the note @AlexeiLevenkov. You're absolutely right